# Javascript/JSON output doesn't show

Tags: javascript, json

I am doing an exercise related with JSON and JavaScript. However, I just could not figure out that what's wrong with my syntax. It should show the links on the ordered list part in HTML, but I got only H2 tag.

Here is the syntax:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Javascript and jason</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>Links</h2>
  <ol id="links">
  </ol>
  <script>

  var info = {
    "full_name":"Ray Villaobos",
    "title" : "Staff Author",
    "links" :[
        {"blog":"http://iviewsource.com"},
        {"facebook":"http://facebook.com/iviewsource"},
        {"youtube":"http://www.youtube.com"},
        {"podcast":"http://feeds.feedburer.com/authoredcontent"},
        {"twitter":"http://twitter.com/planetoftheweb"}
    ]

   };

var output = '';

for (var i=0; i <=info.links.length; i++) {

    for (key in info.links[i]){

        if (info.links[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            output +='<li>' +
            '<a href ="' + info.links[i][key]+
            '">' +'</a>' + 
            '<li>';
        }

       }
    }
    var update = document.getElementById('links');
    update.innerHtml = output;

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: No any errors. In fact, It should show as: Links as a title and then the links as ordered list, I just wondered where are those links, from inspect elements, the ol part has nothing

Comment: In addition to the answer from @putvande, you're also not placing any text inside the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You don't see anything because you have a typo. Remember that JavaScript is case-sensitive.

It should be :

```
update.innerHTML = output;
```

So with uppercase `HTML`.

But it might be better to use `appendChild` like so:

```
var output = '';
var update = document.getElementById('links');
for (var i = 0; i <= info.links.length; i++) {

    for (key in info.links[i]) {

        if (info.links[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute('href', info.links[i][key]);
            a.text = key;
            li.appendChild(a);
            update.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4b0o9he/)

Comment: Hi, tks! I corrected that. But do you know what I got then, it shows Links as  title, then the number from 1 to 10 in 10 rows. After each number, nothing showed?

Comment: That's because you only provided a link for your `a` tag, but no text.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

1. You're not closing your `li` elements; you have another `<li>` where the closing `</li>` should be.
2. You're not putting anything *inside* the `<a>` tags. I'm including `key` as the link text here.
3. `innerHtml` should be `innerHTML`.

```js
var info = {
  "full_name": "Ray Villaobos",
  "title": "Staff Author",
  "links": [{
    "blog": "http://iviewsource.com"
  }, {
    "facebook": "http://facebook.com/iviewsource"
  }, {
    "youtube": "http://www.youtube.com"
  }, {
    "podcast": "http://feeds.feedburer.com/authoredcontent"
  }, {
    "twitter": "http://twitter.com/planetoftheweb"
  }]

};

var output = '';

for (var i = 0; i <= info.links.length; i++) {

  for (key in info.links[i]) {

    if (info.links[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      output += '<li>' +
        '<a href="' + info.links[i][key] +
        '">' + key + '</a>' +
        '</li>';
    }

  }
}
var update = document.getElementById('links');
update.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
 <h2>Links</h2>
<ol id="links">
</ol>
```

Comment: Many tks! I could not vote you up but many tks. Saved my time. :-)